# Eclipse showing errors where they aren't

Tags: java, eclipse

Just look at this piece of code:

```
        for(Person per1 : persons){
         for(Person per2 : persons){
          ArrayList<Person> field1 = per1.getKnownPeople(); //error here
          ArrayList<Person> field2 = per2.getKnownPeople(); //and here
        }}
```

As you can see this is fairly simple. But Eclipse manages to find errors in "per1" and "per2" showing "Cannot be resolved as a variable". How can I fix it?

Comment: are u able to import Person in your class?

Comment: getKnowPeople() returns an array of person? please post your full code for modre advice.

Comment: gRaWEty - that worked, that should be answer :D

Comment: You should use the List interface instead of the ArrayList implementation. You shouldn't care about the type of the list that is returned, what if someone else feels more confident with linkedList

Answer (score 1):

Answer by qRaWEty:
If you do "Project -> Clean..." it will magically repair all that kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I know, that Project-clean solved your problem, but project-refresh might work better if you have just checked out.